# Split string by list of separators and return used separator in the correct order

Tags: c++, beginner

I have built a function that splits a string by an list of separators and returns the used separator in order of usage.

This is the header of the function:

```
vector<string>* split(const string* value, const string* seperators, string* split_by)
```

The function is used like the following:

```
const string value_to_split = "000-000:000-000";
const string seperators = "-:";
string split_by;

auto parts = split(&value_to_split, &seperators, &split_by);
delete parts;
```

> **Example:**
>
> Input
>
> - value => 000-000:000-000
> - seperators => "-:"
>
> Output
>
> - return value => [ '000', '000', '000', '000' ]
> - split_by => "-:-"

This is the functions body:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::vector;

vector<string>* split(const string* value, const string* seperators, string* split_by) {
    vector<string>* splited_string = new vector<string>;
    string current_item = "";
    for (int charIndex = 0; charIndex < value->length(); charIndex++) {
        auto current_char = (*value)[charIndex];
        auto seperator_search = seperators->find(current_char);
        if (seperator_search != string::npos) {
            auto current_seperator = (*seperators)[seperator_search];
            splited_string->push_back(current_item);
            *split_by += current_seperator;
            current_item = "";
        }
        else {
            current_item += current_char;
        }
    }
    splited_string->push_back(current_item);
    return splited_string;
};
```

I mainly want to know if I'm using the language correctly (I'm a C# developer learning C++). But pleace also dont hestitate to tell me about anything that you would do different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The standard library offers [strstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/).
- It seems more natural to look for separators in the string, rather for string characters in separators.
- `value` and `separators` better be passed as `const std::string&` to make sure they are not attempted to be mutated.
- Out parameters are typically frowned upon. Consider returning an `std::pair<std::vector<string>, std::vector<char>>`.

Comment: Because if i pass a const pointer its only garantied that the pointer doesnt change but if I pass it by reference the value cannot change?

Comment: @Dr.Fre depends on what you're making const. In your case you put const correctly.

Comment: @Incomputable so you could write something like `string const * parameter`?

Comment: @Dr.Fre no, it will yield the same thing as current. To make a type const, put const to the right of it, e.g. string* const

Comment: *"Out parameters are typically frowned upon."* [citation-required] Who frowns on these? Returning `std::pair` is a viable option, but it's a subjective interface decision, not a code correctness issue.

Comment: @CodyGray I do to begin with. No citation, it is a just fact of life. And of course the code is correct, no doubt. But it is all about clarity, isn't it?

Comment: Sure. And I think an out parameter is *much* clearer than a packed return value. Of course, better yet is creating an interface that only needs to return a single value.

Answer (score 4):

You don't normally pass in pointers in C++. If you aren't going to modify it you can do a "const reference". They have also made changes that can make passing by value efficient in a lot of cases, at least with regard to standard library objects. Compilers can also optimize to make return by value efficient. So my recommendation would be to get rid of the pointers.

```
vector<string> split_mine(const string& value, const string& seperators, string& split_by) {
   vector<string> splited_string;
    string current_item = "";
    for (unsigned int charIndex = 0; charIndex < value.length(); charIndex++) {
        auto current_char = value[charIndex];
        auto seperator_search = seperators.find(current_char);
        if (seperator_search != string::npos) {
            auto current_seperator = seperators[seperator_search];
            splited_string.push_back(current_item);
            split_by += current_seperator;
            current_item = "";
        }
        else {
            current_item += current_char;
        }
    }
    splited_string.push_back(current_item);
    return splited_string;
}
```

As mentioned in the other answer, you can get rid of your reference (modifiable) parameter by returning it as part of a pair:

```
#include <utility>
using std::pair;

pair<vector<string>,string> split3(const string& value, const string& seperators) 
{
   string split_by;
   vector<string> splited_string;
    string current_item = "";
    for (unsigned int charIndex = 0; charIndex < value.length(); charIndex++) {
        auto current_char = value[charIndex];
        auto seperator_search = seperators.find(current_char);
        if (seperator_search != string::npos) {
            auto current_seperator = seperators[seperator_search];
            splited_string.push_back(current_item);
            split_by += current_seperator;
            current_item = "";
        }
        else {
            current_item += current_char;
        }
    }
    splited_string.push_back(current_item);
    return std::make_pair(splited_string,split_by);
}

int main(void)
{   

   pair<vector<string>,string> results = split3(value,separators);
   std::cout << "entry 1:" << results.first[0] << std::endl;
   std::cout << "entry 2:" << results.first[1] << std::endl;
   std::cout << "entry 3:" << results.first[2] << std::endl;
   std::cout << "split_by: " << results.second << std::endl;

}
```

If you insist on returning heap-allocated objects you should wrap them in a “smart” pointer for automatic deletion once the object goes out of scope to avoid memory leaks:

```
std::pair<std::unique_ptr<vector<string>>, string> split3_smart_pointer(...)
{
    string split_by;
    std::unique_ptr<vector<string>> splited_string(new vector<string>());
    string current_item = "";
    for (unsigned int charIndex = 0; charIndex < value.length(); charIndex++) {
        auto current_char = value[charIndex];
        auto seperator_search = seperators.find(current_char);
        if (seperator_search != string::npos) {
            auto current_seperator = seperators[seperator_search];
            splited_string->push_back(current_item);
            split_by += current_seperator;
            current_item = "";
        }
        else {
            current_item += current_char;
        }
    }
    splited_string->push_back(current_item);
    return std::make_pair(std::move(splited_string), split_by);
}
```

Comment: Would you ever return an heap allocated object pointer without wrapping it in an smart pointer?

Comment: @Dr.Fre There may be cases where that is preferred or necessary but I can't name them.